# How do multiple buffers for attributes work in openGL (ES) shaders and C++ api

Tags: c++, opengl-es, glsl, shader, opengl-es-3.0

I have the proverbial cube sample and have been writing some code to test it all and learn more about shaders. My question is about how multiple buffers are assigned to access within the shader and how one writes shader code to reference them. The samples out there seem to rely on some sort of implicit referencing defaults that hide what is really happening and how one manipulates it in the samples.

My buffer setup is as follows ( data omitted )

```
        glGenBuffers(1, &vertexPosObject);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexPosObject);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
            sizeof(Vec3f), (void*)0);

        /* load index buffer with array of indices */
        glGenBuffers(1, &indexBufferObject);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBufferObject);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        /* load color buffer with array of colors */
        glGenBuffers(1, &colorBufferObject);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBufferObject);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertColors), vertColors, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
            sizeof(Vec4f), 0);
```

With this I get a cube drawing and can rotate it. with.

```
        Matrix4d modelView;
        double rot = rc.timing().frameTime()*.3;
        rot = fmod(rot, ARTD_M_PI * 2);
        modelView.setRotation(Vec3d(0, 1, 1), rot);
        artdGlUniformMatrix4(modelViewId, modelView); // convenience call
```

then I can draw it below

```
        glUseProgram(cubeShader);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexPosObject);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBufferObject);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBufferObject);

        const int vertexCount = 36;
        const int type = GL_UNSIGNED_INT; // unsigned short ??
        const int firstIndex = 0;

        // vertexCount is the number of verts in your vertex array object
        // firstIndex is the first index to use in an array of offsets (element index) into the vertex data.

        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, vertexCount, type, (void *)firstIndex);

        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
```

I have been assuming the vertex array is assigned a "slot" with

```
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
```

And that slot "0" is **implicitly** what the shader takes as its input vertices. (???)

So I figured I'd try assigning the color array to slot "1", so the index array handle is passed directly into glDrawElements() and does retrieve the vertices for input in the shader using the index array addressing the buffer assigned to slot "0".

I general, I assumed one might want multiple buffers for all sorts of stuff like normals, colors, etc. and one would need to access the values of these buffers addressing them with the indices. So a general case answer would be desirable.

My question is, how does one access the color array buffer in the shader as well as accessing other buffers as indexable arrays in the vertex shader?

How does one bind buffers to various shader accessible identifiers and how does one access them from these identifiers within shader code.  Understanding these relationships is key.

Currently this shader pair works for drawing the cube with calculated colors.

```
    "uniform mat4 Projection;\n"
    "uniform mat4 Model;\n"

    "attribute vec4 vPosition;\n"
    "varying vec3 color;\n"
    "void main(){\n"
        "mat4 MVP = Model * Projection;\n"
        "gl_Position = vPosition * MVP;\n"
        "color = gl_Position.xyz + vec3(0.5);\n"
    "}\n"
```

Fragment shader

```
   "precision mediump float;\n"
    "varying vec3 color;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
        "gl_FragColor = vec4 ( color, 1.0 );\n"
    "}\n"
```

Pardon C++ strings :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use the color attribute, the you have to add a new attribute to the shader:

*Vertex shader*

```
attribute vec4 vPosition;
attribute vec4 vColor;

varying vec4 color;

uniform mat4 Projection;
uniform mat4 Model;

void main()
{
    mat4 MVP    = Model * Projection;
    gl_Position = vPosition * MVP;
    color       = vColor;
}
```

After the shader program is linked by [`glLinkProgram`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glLinkProgram.xml), the attribute index can be retrieved through [`glGetAttribLocation`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glGetAttribLocation.xml):

```
GLuint cubeShader = ....;

glLinkProgram(cubeShader);

GLint pos_attr_i   = glGetAttribLocation(cubeShader, "vPosition");
GLint color_attr_i = glGetAttribLocation(cubeShader, "vColor");
```

This are the attribute indices which have to be use in [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) respectively [`glEnableVertexAttribArray`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glEnableVertexAttribArray.xhtml):

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexPosObject);
glVertexAttribPointer(pos_attr_i, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vec3f), (void*)0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBufferObject);
glVertexAttribPointer(color_attr_i, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vec4f), 0);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(pos_attr_i);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(color_attr_i);
```

Comment: sounds like a part of the puzzle - so you can get the "slot" id of the attributes in the shader.  But you need to connect two things the client side buffer (handle) and the server side shader attibute index.

Comment: @peterk There is nothing magic and no puzzle at all. This is all well documented. If a named array buffer object is bound then `glVertexAttribPointer` refers to this buffer. The "slot" is the attribute index and the link between the shader program and the state vector of the (default) vertex array object. `glVertexAttribPointer` sets the states in the vertex array object.

Comment: Ahh ok its a "paris in the the spring thing" I see it as the first argument to glVertexAttrribPointer :)  Thanks !

Comment: @peterk You're welcome. I know this all seem complicate and confusing. But the key is, that at OpenGL everything is stated and keeps is state until it is not explicitly changed.

Comment: That I understood but so much sample code is a mix of deprecated calls etc.  and the docs often don't give you the links between things.  simple when you discover it people just hard code a '0' because most compilers will simply default the first attribute declared to '0' but one can't assume such things :)

Anyway I have a nice rotating colored cube !!

Comment: @peterk All the graphic drivers I know, enumerate the attributes starting by 0. But that is not specified in the standard. The automatic attribute index of an attribute can be any number. The attribute index can be set explicitly [`glBindAttribLocation`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glBindAttribLocation.xhtml) before `glLinkProgram` or in shader code by [Layout Qualifier](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Vertex_shader_attribute_index) (`layout(location = 1) in vec4 vColor;`. I don't know since which GLSL ES version this is supported.

Comment: they say move this discussion to "chat" - hmmm - I have written drivers for other things and did work building DirectX many years ago. The API makes lots of sense but a dump of API calls doesn't explain the architecture :)  I have never used the "chat" here do you use it does it provide email echoing ? is it like discussion groups ?  I do prefer named symbols as one can specify groups of shaders and linkages in text files to load them at run time and create "readable" source and automatically query things.